# 3 way simultaneous equations

Tags: matrices

For which values of $a,b$ do the following simultaneous equations have infinitely many solutions: $2x + 3y + z = 6$, $-x + y + 2z = 7$, and $ax + y + 4z =b$, I started by writing the system as a matrix and then finding the determinant of said matrix, which I get to be $3a + 15$, this has to be $0$ for the system to have infinitely many solutions, implying $a=-3$. However I am now stuck and would like some pointers/help, thanks!

Comment: Row ops on the augmented matrix to determine $b$.  Anyway, is there a typo in your second equation?

Comment: The inverse doesn't exist if $a=-3$

Comment: That is why I say row ops rather than multiply by nonexistent inverse matrix.

Comment: I have not encountered the term row ops before

Comment: What do you mean by it?

Comment: No. I have found $a$ by considering when the matrix is singular, I am not stuck on how to find $b$.

Comment: $$ \left( 
\begin{array}{rrr|r} 
2 & 3 & 1 & 6 \\ 
-1 & 1 & 2 & 7 \\ 
a & 1 & 4 & b \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$  You may add a multiple of one row to another row.  If convenient you may multiply any row by a nonzero constant. Once you get the square part to be upper triangular, number of soultions should be evident

Comment: I have never seen this matrix notation before.  Where can I learn more? I do not understand any of your comment other than the square matrix bit

Comment: https://industri.fatek.unpatti.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/037-Elementary-Linear-Algebra-Applications-Version-Howard-Anton-Chris-Rorres-Edisi-1-2013.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the extra reading material

Comment: This book goes far above my level, could you write up an answer giving the information I need to solve the problem, then I can mark it as answered and work on understanding it.

Comment: Surely, if you've been set this question, you can solve a system of equations like this, if there were specific numbers for $a$ and $b$, right? Have you tried applying those same methods, where $a$ is $-3$, but $b$ remains unknown, and see what you get?

Comment: I just solved it in a minute after I stopped looking at the worked solution, their method was wrong lol and I had been trying to understand it.....